# emotional sounding boards -- what does this mean?

Tags: meaning

Example with [a context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_T._Kirk):

> James Tiberius "Jim" Kirk is a fictional character in the Star Trek media franchise, appearing in numerous television episodes, films, books, comics, and video games. As the captain of the starship USS Enterprise, Kirk leads his crew as they explore "where no man has gone before". Often, the characters of Spock and Leonard McCoy act as his logical and emotional sounding **boards**, respectively.

I'm not really sure how to understand *boards* in this Wiki article. A board is usually a group of people within an organization that convene to make important decisions. Not sure if that has anything to do with what they are talking about in the article. Any idea?

Comment: Be careful not to parse this as "emotional-sounding board." It's definitely not a weeping plank of wood! :-)

Comment: "sounding board" is the noun phrase that you can Google for yourself and find the meaning (search for: `sounding board define`). In this excerpt, Spock is the logical sounding board and McCoy is the emotional sounding board.

Comment: (Dr) Spock will give feedback based on logic; McCoy will give feedback based on emotion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A "sounding board" is, literally, a piece of wood that is placed behind a speaker so that the sound bounces off and out into the audience, rather than diffusing out in all directions. That is, the "board" is not a board in the sense of "committee", but rather a piece of wood. This is no doubt not so important today when we mostly rely on microphones and electrical speakers, but was important in an age when buildings had to be designed to amplify a speaker's voice in less technologically demanding ways.

A literal sounding board just bounces sound around: it doesn't answer back or engage in conversation. So metaphorically, a "sounding board" is someone who listens to what you have to say but doesn't offer substantive comments. People often say that some other person is or was their "sounding board" when they had new ideas or were feeling depressed: someone who would offer encouragement and maybe minor suggestions, but who would mostly just listen.

About 90% of the time these days, when you hear "sounding board" people are talking in this metaphorical sense, and not about literal sounding boards.

Comment: Just for clarification, because it took me a second to figure it out: in "placed behind a **speaker**" I assume you mean an "someone who is speaking" rather than "a mechanical device for producing sound"?

Comment: If you trust Wikipedia, a [sounding board](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sounding_board) reflects, shapes and amplifies a person's speech, but a [sound board](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_board) is much more general.  I'm not sure that the distinction matters.  Metaphorically, Kirk uses Spock to reflect, shape and understand his own tactical and analytical thinking, just as he uses McCoy to better understand his own feelings and moral judgments.  Conversations with Spock reflect the smart thing to do; conversations with McCoy reflect the right thing to do.

Comment: @sabre Oh, yes, placed behind a person who is speaking. See, that's where language can be ambiguous. I knew exactly what I meant when I wrote the sentence ...

Comment: To me, a "sound board" is an electronic device used in auditoriums and recording studios to control the volume of sound (and probably other characteristics) coming from a variety of sources. The ones I've seen have a bunch of sliders, i.e. knobs that can be moved up and down in a slot, each one controlling the volume from one source. Sources might include microphones places at various places on a stage, recorded music, sound effects, etc. I just did a web search and I am reminded that a "sound board" is also the piece of wood in a string instrument that vibrates with the strings to ...

Comment: ... amplify the sound. And apparently the phrase has half a dozen other meanings that I'm not familiar with.